# Change CSS background with jQuery conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, conditional-statements

I'm building some html thermometers, which are animated with jQuery in order to show represent a percentage number (as you can see [in the **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rubjm9/rpxr4bjj/) I've built).

What I want, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, is to get the thermometer's color to change depending the level they are representing. For instance in the Fiddle's script those under 80 should be color blue, and those over 80 should be yellow, but all of them turn out blue.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$('.lvl').each(function(){
    var level = $(this).text();
    $(this).animate( {
        width: level+'%'
    }, 1000);

    var lvlwidth = $(this).width();
    if (lvlwidth < 80) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    } else if (lvlwidth > 80) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
});
```

**Update:** As I say in the comments below, what I want is the bar to dynamically change color as it grows, so for example to be blue when it's under 40, then turn yellow, and when it reaches 80 turn red.

Comment: You're checking the width as the animation starts, and at that point the elements have no width. Why aren't you just using the `level` variable, as you already have the number you want there ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/rpxr4bjj/1/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. I didn't do it that was because I was hoping to get it to change dynamically as it grew, so to be initially one color, change to another once it reaches 40, and then change again when it reaches 80. The `level` variable is fixed while the `width` changes.

Comment: It's possible to do what you wan't, but that would be more complicated and require using the `step` callback in jQuery's `animate`

Comment: "*...blue when it's under 40, then turn yellow, and when it reaches 80 turn red*" so it should be yellow at `60`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/rpxr4bjj/3/

```
$('.lvl').each(function () {
    var level = $(this).text();
    $(this).animate({
        width: level + '%',
    }, {
        progress: function () {


            if (level < 80) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
            } else if (level > 80) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        }
    }, 3000);


});
```

Comment: Thanks @dm4web, but don't they all go yellow now? aren't those under `width: 80%` supposed to stay blue in this example?

Comment: i test in FF and works. In chrome they all yellow. and I will look to

Comment: I added a correction. problem was the width not Chrome or FF.

Comment: Thanks again @dm4web. Do you think there's a way of getting the bars to all start in the same color and change colors as they animate, instead of being all the way the same color?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/2nbbbcxc/1/ (i made some tweaks you may disregard, like a third color level, and transitions)

Comment: Brilliant @FabioSilva and @dm4web! I was actually planning to add a third color and transitions myself as the next step ;)

Comment: @dm4web you could move wParent out of the animation step, because its value is always the same. You could also divide 100 by it, saving some operations in each iteration. :)

Comment: @FábioSilva of course, but this can have different widths and that the script works :)